# Reversed numbers puzzle

Tags: php, logic, puzzle

I'm are trying to teach myself to be better at programming. Part of this I have been taking puzzle that I find in newspapers and magazines and trying to find programming solutions

Today I seen a puzzle regarding numbers that are the reversed when multiplied by a number from 2-9. The example given was 1089 * 9 = 9801.

I have started to write a program in php to find the numbers this applies to and adds them to an array.

First I created a loop to cycle through the possible numbers. I then reversed each of the numbers and created a function to compare the numbered and the reversed number. The function then returns numbers that meet the criteria and adds them to an array.

This is what I have so far...

```
<?php

        function mul(){ // multiply number from loop

            for($i=2;$i<=9;$i++){

                $new = $num * $i;

                    if($new == $re){
                    return $new;    
                    }
                    else{
                    return;
                    }
            }
        }

        $arr =  array();

        for ($num = 1000; $num <10000; $num++) { //loop through possible numbers

                      $re =  strrev($num); // get reverse of number
                      func($re,$num); //multiply number and return correct numbers
                      $arr.push($new); //add to array??
         }
 ?>
```

I'm still very new to php and I find understanding programming, any pointers on a more logical way of doing this puzzle would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes it doesn't work, I put it up to see if anyone could tell me if I'm on the right direction, thanks

Comment: Well, `$arr.push` looks like something you took from JavaScript, there's no function `func()`, and your function `mul()` takes no arguments.

Comment: This isn't your real code. @Madara points out you're calling `func()` when there is none and `mul()` takes no arguments (but you also never call `mul()`). Posting nonsense and pretending it's code is a waste of everyone's time (including yours). Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Thanks, lol probably shouldnt try learn JS and PHP at the same time.

Comment: oops sorry mul() and func() are meant to be the same function, I just to clarify as i'm still very new to this. When a function is created to I have to specify what variables it takes or can do I enter them when the are called like I did with func($re,$num);?  - This isnt a homework assignment, I already have graduated :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution with a nested loop. Quick and dirty.

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 1000; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    for ($m = 2; $m < 10; $m++) {
        if ($i*$m == (int)strrev($i)) {
            $result[] = array($i, $m);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

I'd like to expand on this line:

```
if ($i*$m == (int) strrev($i)) {
```

One side is `$i*$m`, easy, the multipication.

On the other, we have `(int)strrev($i)`, which means "Take `$i`, cast it to a string, and reverse that. Then cast it back into an `int`.

If that evaluates to true, an array containing `$i` and `m` is inserted into the `$result` array.

Comment: This program doesn't find them all... nor does it add them to an array

Comment: @durron597: It very much successfully outputs `1089`, which is the correct solution. Where is the problem? OP never said anything about an array being the requirement (since the solution only contains one number, an array seems silly to me).

Comment: 1089 as an example number, there should be multiple numbers that fit the criteria. Thank you for your example.

Comment: What about `2178 * 4`? Also, you don't have to go to `10000`, because once you get over `5000` the number won't have the same number of digits even for `m=2`

Comment: From 1 to 1000000 its `1089 * 9` , `2178 * 4` ,`10989 * 9` ,`21978 * 4` , `109989 * 9` , `219978 * 4`

Comment: @Ciaran: I've edited my answer, both solutions would show up.

Comment: @Baba: Indeed, but OP only asked (at least as inferred from his code), from 1000 to 10000, which leads me to think he only wants 4 digit numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for logical questions to solve to preparing for my interview. Thanks for sharing this question.I have solved this question but using Java.I have used very basic concept.I hope you can understand and convert it to php.

```
public static boolean processNumber(int number)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=9;i++)
    {
        int reverseNumber=number*i;
        boolean status=checkReverse(reverseNumber,number);
        if(status)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean checkReverse(int reverseNumber,int numberOriginal)
{
    int number=reverseNumber;
    int reverse=0,digit;
    do
    {
        digit=number%10;
        number=number/10;
        reverse=reverse*10+digit;
    }while(number>0);

    if(reverse==numberOriginal)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is my little effort towards programming check if it satisfy your requirements 

$n = 1089;
$temp = $n;
$sum =0;
//reversing given number
while($n>1){
  $rem = $n%10;
  $sum = $sum*10 + $rem;
  $n = $n/10;
}
//checking for digit that satisfy criteria
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
  if($i*$temp == $sum){
    echo "$temp * $i = $sum";
  }
}
```